# How can i use react-toastify from hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-toastify

I found **useToast** and **useToastContainer**, but documentation is absent and i don't understand how tu use these hooks. Can anyone provide some info about these hooks?

Comment: did you went through this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toast-notifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `toasts` inherit `ToastContainer’s` props. Props defined on toast supersede ToastContainer’s props.

There are two ways you can use `toasts` in your application:

> **1. Define `ToastContainer` inside the component**

```
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
  
  const App = () => {
    notify = () => toast("Wow so easy !");

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={notify}>Notify !</button>

        // You can add <ToastContainer /> in root component as well.
        <ToastContainer />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

> **2. Call `toast.configure()` once in your app. At the `root` of your app is the best place.**

The library will mount a `ToastContainer` for you if none is mounted.

```
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
  
   // Call it once in your app. At the root of your app is the best place
  toast.configure()
  
  const App = () => {
    notify = () => toast("Wow so easy !");

    return (
        <button onClick={notify}>Notify !</button>
    );
  }
```

You can use either of them. I prefer the **2nd** method because you only need to define `toast.configure()` which is quite clean way to add it.

> You can add configuration as per your need like below:

```
toast.configure({
  autoClose: 8000,
  draggable: false,
  //etc you get the idea
});
```

#### EDIT

If you want to use toast hooks, then you must wrap your app with the ToastProvider to have access to its context elsewhere within your app.

```
import { ToastProvider, useToasts } from 'react-toast-notifications'

const FormWithToasts = () => {
  const { addToast } = useToasts()

  const onSubmit = async value => {
    const { error } = await dataPersistenceLayer(value)

    if (error) {
      addToast(error.message, { appearance: 'error' })
    } else {
      addToast('Saved Successfully', { appearance: 'success' })
    }
  }

  return <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>...</form>
}

const App = () => (
  <ToastProvider>
    <FormWithToasts />
  </ToastProvider>
)
```

Comment: You can't define ToastContainer and use toast() from custom hook, that's the problem. If you know how to use it, i will be very happy.

Comment: you must wrap your app with the ToastProvider to have access to its context elsewhere within your app. https://github.com/jossmac/react-toast-notifications#use

Comment: That is... a completely different framework...