# Use react toastify in react js

Tags: reactjs

Im using react-toastify but it throws an error about "Invalid Hook Call". here is my code:

[image]

and here is my error:

[image]

can anyone help me?

Comment: Please don't share your code into a image, include it into your questions details with a proper format. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

your code is working on codesandbox see this https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-snowflake-897rx?file=/src/App.js

try running the code without the context provider component and also try importing react in the same file.

Comment: tnx. I saw it but in my project I still have an errro about <ToastContainer /> :(

Comment: @DanielFiroozi have you imported React in this file ?

Comment: Yeah I added. everything is OK but not about react-toastify. It returns error in <ToastContainer />

Comment: @DanielFiroozi try without <ToastContainer /> see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62820758/how-can-i-use-react-toastify-from-hook

Comment: Tnx a lot my friend. I replaced <ToastContainer /> with toast.configure and error solved. but now It printed some numbers in body?

Comment: @DanielFiroozi check this https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-snowflake-897rx?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you install `toastify` for the correct folder (project folder). If it is installed in the wrong location, you can change the path using:

```
cd {folder name}
```

in the command line and then install `toastify` again.